# How do I force Firefox or any other browser to check for CRLs

Tags: ssl

I am trying to see if I can watch the traffic that is sent and received when a browser checks for CRLs. All I can see with the latest version of Firefox is setting for OCSP. I dont see anything where I can force it to check CRLs. Is this something that Firefox doesn't give control of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firefox has moved some time ago to use only OCSP and no longer CRL:](https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:ImprovingRevocation#Remove_CRL_User-Interface)

> As of Firefox 24, the user-interface for importing CRLs via Firefox has been removed. Auto-importing/updating of CRLs through Firefox has also been removed. NSS still supports CRLs, but Firefox is moving away from checking CRLs, and moving towards using a revocation list push mechanism.

Comment: So Firefox doesn't use CRLs and only relies on OCSP? Or does it do CRLs depending on the certificate? In short is CRL checking non existent in Firefox?

Comment: I guess as per [this][1] article, "The latest version of Firefox removed the last vestiges of CRL checking: previously CRLs were checked only for EV certificates when OCSP failed." [1]:http://news.netcraft.com/archives/2014/04/24/certificate-revocation-why-browsers-remain-affected-by-heartbleed.html

Comment: I've edited the response to make it clearer, that OCSP is the only way now.